# How to print japanese log in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: logging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I use logback to print log in Google Cloud Functions in java.
I want to print Japanese log, but the log has all be strange characters.
How can I print the log in my Java code？

My logback setting is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender"
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
      <fieldNames>
        <timestamp>[ignore]</timestamp>
        <version>[ignore]</version>
        <logger>[ignore]</logger>
        <thread>[ignore]</thread>
        <level>[ignore]</level>
        <levelValue>[ignore]</levelValue>
      </fieldNames>
      <charset class="java.nio.charset.Charset">UTF-8</charset>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

My code to print the log

```
logger.info("処理開始:加工前処理", kv("severity", "NOTICE"));
```

And the log is

```
{
    "textPayload": "������������:���������������",
    "insertId": "000000-47138e32-2a00-40ec-ad45-88c03dffc271",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "xxxxxx",
        "region": "asia-northeast1",
        "function_name": "function-2"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2020-11-05T09:24:46.633Z",
    "severity": "NOTICE",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": "sa3kufvievy8"
    },
    "logName": "projects/xxxxxx/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/xxxxxx/traces/17915c7ed95b6d275b424e95f1a5b94b",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2020-11-05T09:24:56.671368622Z"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Logback is not very well supported in GCP functions as [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/java-logging#logback). so I suggest using the Java Logging API which is already included in Cloud Functions.

an example code would be:

**Folders structure**:

src --> main --> java --> com --> example --> Example.java

pom.xml

**Example.java**

```
package com.example;

import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Example implements HttpFunction {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName());

  @Override
  public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
      throws IOException {

    logger.info("処理開始:加工前処理");

    BufferedWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write("Messages successfully logged!");
  }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.cloud.functions</groupId>
  <artifactId>functions-logging-log-hello-world</artifactId>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.21</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Required for Function primitives -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
      <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!--
          Google Cloud Functions Framework Maven plugin
          This plugin allows you to run Cloud Functions Java code
          locally. Use the following terminal command to run a
          given function locally:
          mvn function:run -Drun.functionTarget=your.package.yourFunction
        -->
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
        <artifactId>function-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <functionTarget>functions.Example</functionTarget>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <!-- version 3.0.0-M4 does not load JUnit5 correctly -->
        <!-- see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1750 -->
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
          <reportNameSuffix>sponge_log</reportNameSuffix>
          <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It works. And logback alse works. I just missed the setting of <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> in pom.xml.